# How to daisy chain SWD Debug port

Tags: arm, debugging, swd

I have multiple mcu's that are configured to communicate with bus topology. I have 10 pins (4 of them is occupied by now)

I need to debug (update firmware online, etc) all of these mcu's. I read [this article](http://www.arm.com/products/system-ip/debug-trace/coresight-soc-components/serial-wire-debug.php) but I didn't understand how to achieve the goal.

Question: How can I daisy chain these mcu's?

MCU: STM32F407VG

Debug protocol: SWD

Comment: Your development tools need to support it.

Comment: I need the algorithm, I can build the development tool.

Comment: I think that you need to license that from ARM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I daisy chain these mcu's?
>   MCU: STM32F407VG
>   Debug protocol: SWD

These MCUs support JTAG and SWD. While JTAG supports a daisy chain configuration, SWD does *not*. There is a multi drop extension in SWD 2.0 protocol, but I am pretty sure your MCU does not implement this.

If you really want to debug multiple chips in a daisy chain, use JTAG. Beware: Tool configuration(s) may be non-trivial to do.

Note that you might want to separate a `firmware update` from your `debugging` scenario. Firmware updates can be done in multiple ways using a bootloader, so SWD or JTAG is not required in this case.

Comment: I need to be sure that I can not brick the device after a firmware update. I can fall back to the previous firmware if anything happens as far as I would use a debug port (JTAG or SWD). I'm not sure if bootloader option gives me that opportunity. 

My emergency plan is as follows: I can create point to point routes between mcu's and use every mcu as a proxy.

Comment: Here is the last solution we have: https://github.com/aktos-io/stm-flasher This is a command line utility that loads the firmware over uart.

Answer (score 0):

I use mux chips, such as [74LVC1G18](https://www.ti.com/general/docs/suppproductinfo.tsp?distId=10&gotoUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fgpn%2Fsn74lvc1g18) or [74LVC1G19](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74LVC1G19.pdf) for clock, and [DG4157E](https://www.vishay.com/docs/75778/dg4157e.pdf) for data. (Data requires an analog switch because it is bi-directional.)

There are of course higher-radix mux chips in case you want to program more devices from the same programmer.