# Programming Multiple STM32F4 Controllers

Tags: pcb, jtag

I Have designed a board that contain 3 ICs of (STM32F407) as shown in the figure below.
these chips programmed by using (SWDIO AND SWCLK) for each chip.

Can I use JTAG pins to programme these three chips with the same set of pins??
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to daisy chain SWD Debug port](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/102239/how-to-daisy-chain-swd-debug-port)

Comment: you can't daisy-chain SWD, but you can daisy-chain JTAG. These microcontroller support both, so no problem.

Comment: also, it seems you've not adhered to the decoupling caps requirements for these MCUs; this thing will not run reliably.

Comment: also, these monsters cost > 8 € a piece even in large quantities. This really looks like you'd be better off with a single faster application processor, and a cheaper Cortex-M0 for control / bringup tasks than three of these. Strong recommendation to rethink your software design! Try something like the STM32MP1 instead, if you need to crunch a lot of numbers. If you don't have to crunch a lot of numbers: these larger microcontrollers are probably overkill...

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks a lot for your feedback, I will check that question.
 decoupling capacitors are located in the bottom layer.
I will take in consideration changing these controllers to a cheaper one.

Comment: oh, you want to assemble SMD components on both sides? That's tedious if you do it yourself (can't just put in an oven) and expensive if you pay someone to do it.

Comment: @MarcusMüller no no, I am working with a manufacturer who fabricate the board and also assemble all components. a single board cost around 350$, how much cheaper do you think it will be if there is no component on the bottom layer?!

Comment: I don't know, gotta ask them! But if you do two-sided assembly, you either need components that withstand repeated soldering, or glue to hold the bottom components during soldering, so that's why it's usually problematic. 350€ is quite a solid price, I'd expect high quality at that (assuming your board isn't much larger and doesn't have hundreds of additional components to the left).

Comment: anyway, if you get this assembled anyway, I'd recommend opting for QFN or BGA parts instead of your QFP, at least if they're cheaper: often makes the layout look nicer, and if that was critical (doesn't look like it, at all), more compact.

Comment: Also, are you sure U3, U9 and U12 are the right footprint? these look like SOIC-14, but for hand-soldering

Comment: unless they're at the bottom (if so: why?), the LEDs are missing serious resistors.

Comment: This board still under development so I have used the same chip and package in the STM32F4discovery board, yes these are the right footprint for U3,U9 and U12, In fact I do not put in consideration how will the manufacturer assemble any component unless he tell me to change it.
I really appreciate your notes :) :)

Comment: Why do you have three microcontrollers on the same PCB? What to they do? If you only need one, you don't need to even think about chaining JTAG or having separate SWD ports.

Comment: @BaselTahboub if you're sure they are the right footprints, then go ahead. But: your manufacturer is *not* a contract board designer. They won't tell you whether your choice of footprint is optimal, only if it will absolutely not work. (and even that can be lucky for more subtle problems).

Comment: @Justme the application required  three microcontrollers

Comment: @BaselTahboub I'm almost certain that is a design shortcoming of your application, really; you don't seem to be using any more peripherals than a single microcontroller would have. But it's your product, so: your thing; we offered to discuss your application, you won't, so, nothing we can do.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I really appreciate all the notes that you have added and I will take it into consideration in the next upgrade.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Hi Marcus 
I have back to upgrade this board to the next version, can we discuss all the notes that you have mentioned before, and if there is others points you may add, thanks .